# Convolutional inverse of distribution (Van Dijk)

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, distribution-theory, convolution

I am going over the problems in van Dijk's distribution theory book and trying to find the (convolution) inverse of the following distributions:

$$S=\delta''+H,\quad T=He^x +\delta'$$
using Heaviside calculus but I'm not sure the solutions make sense. First (using Heaviside symbolic calculus)

$$S=H+\delta''=\frac{1}{\delta'}+\delta''=\frac{\delta'\delta''+1}{\delta'}=\frac{\delta'''+1}{\delta'}$$
so the inverse of $S$ is given by
$$\delta' (\delta'''+1)^{-1}=\delta' H Z$$
where $Z$ solves $(d^3+1)Z=0$
but this doesn't seem correct. For $T$ I get using $(He^x)^{-1}=\delta'-\delta$
$$T=He^x + \delta' = \frac{1}{\delta'-\delta}+\delta'=\frac{\delta''-\delta'}{\delta'-\delta}$$
and so $T^{-1}=(\delta'-\delta)(\delta''-\delta')^{-1}$
Solving the ODE $(d^2-d)Z=0$ with $Z(0)=0,Z'(0)=1$ I get the solution
$$(\delta''-\delta')^{-1} =H(e^x-1)=He^x-H$$
and so
$$T^{-1}=(\delta'-\delta)(e^x H-H)=H+e\delta-\delta'$$
which again, I'm not sure is correct!
Hints/references/Feedback appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean with $Z$ solves $(d^3+1)Z=0$.

The Laplace transform of $\delta'''+\delta$ is $1+s^3$ and $\frac1{1+s^3} = \frac1{3\zeta_6^2}\frac{1}{s-\zeta_6}+\frac1{3\zeta_6^6}\frac{1}{s-\zeta_6^3}+\frac1{3\zeta_6^{10}}\frac{1}{s-\zeta_6^5}$ whose (causal) inverse Laplace transform is $U=\frac1{3\zeta_6^2} e^{\zeta_6 t}+\frac1{3\zeta_6^{6}} e^{\zeta_6^3 t}+\frac1{3\zeta_6^{10}} e^{\zeta_6^5 t})1_{t>0}$ which is the convolution inverse of $\delta'''+\delta= S'$ so the convolution inverse of $S$ is $U'$

Comment: Thank you but I'm trying to follow the recipe in the book! There he says the inverse of $D\delta$ for $D$ an ODP is given by $HZ$ where $Z$ solves $DZ=0$ with initivial condition $Z(0)=Z'(0)=0$ etc up until $Z^{m-1}(0)=1$

Comment: That's the same thing: do the partial fraction decomposition of $\frac1{1+D^3}$ (inverse of differential operator $(1+D^3)f=f+f'''$) you'll get $\sum_{j=1}^3 \frac{a_j}{b_j+D}$ so you need the inverse of $b_j+D$, what I did in my answer.

Comment: Ok that you. What about the other part of the question/references?